# Rebuild all files if template changes

Tags: gulp, gulp-watch

I'm using gulp to convert markdown files to HTML, and using the [gulp-watch](https://github.com/floatdrop/gulp-watch) plugin (**not** the [gulp.watch](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/API.md#gulpwatchglob--opts-tasks-or-gulpwatchglob--opts-cb) API function) to rebuild files if they change. Works great!

```js
gulp.task('markdown', function () {
  gulp.src('src/**/*.md')
      .pipe(watch('src/**/*.md'))
      .pipe(markdown())
      .pipe(template('templates/md.tpl'))
      .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
});
```

The problem is that the pipeline `src` is the markdown files, but within the pipeline I also reference a template file.  If that template changes, all the markdown files need to be rebuilt.  Is there a way to express that dependency in gulp/gulp-watch?

I tried using gulp.watch (the API function) to watch the template and run the 'markdown' task if it changes ...

```js
gulp.watch('templates/md.tpl', ['markdown']);
```

... but that didn't work.  Nothing happens.  I assume having gulp-watch in the pipeline prevents it from doing anything.

I guess I could create a two tasks, one with gulp-watch and one without, and use the one without to force a full rebuild. I'd rather not, because then it becomes an ongoing problem to keep the two in sync.

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I guess I could create a two tasks, one with gulp-watch and one without, and use the one without to force a full rebuild. I'd rather not, because then it becomes an ongoing problem to keep the two in sync.

Remember, gulp is just JavaScript.

Simply write a function that constructs the stream with or without the `watch()` step depending on a parameter that you pass. The [`gulp-if`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-if) plugin let's you write something like this in a very concise way (although it's not necessary and could be done without it).

Here's how I would do it:

```
var gulpIf = require('gulp-if');

function processMarkdown(opts) {
  gulp.src('src/**/*.md')
    .pipe(gulpIf(opts.watch, watch('src/**/*.md')))
    .pipe(markdown())
    .pipe(template('templates/md.tpl'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
}

gulp.task('markdown', function() {
  processMarkdown({watch: true});
  watch('templates/md.tpl', function() {
    processMarkdown({watch: false});
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can specify gulp `src` as an array, too:

```
gulp.src(['src/**/*.md', 'templates/md.tpl'])
```

Comment: I know you can use multiple wildcards to `src`, but I'm not sure how that helps.  How would changing the template force all the markdown files to rebuild?  And wouldn't I also end up with the template file in the pipeline?  I don't want to process the template itself in the markdown pipeline.